# Installing Ubuntu Mate on Virtualbox - screen is a mess

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-mate

I have a virtualbox and I'am trying to install Ubuntu Mate on it.

The system starts but when the GUI starts the screen is a total mess instead of displaying the installation.

My settings in virtualbox are:

Ubuntu 32 bit
1024MB Base memory
128mb video memory
chipset PIIX3

3d acceleration enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As memory serves me, switching TTY's should fix the problem.

To fix your video problem, hit the  <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, followed by <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. It's a bug.

On a Mac, you may have to <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: I did actually host_key + F7, followed by host_key + F1